# Tomcat LogFactory, print an ERROR when upgrading spring version and java version

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging

I'm upgrading from spring 2.7 to spring 3.0.9 (also using JDK17)

when running the SERVER, I got this ERROR, but the Application still works.

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1457)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3.run(LogFactory.java:1237)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getResourceAsStream(LogFactory.java:1233)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:530)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<clinit>(TomcatWebServer.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:488)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
```

any ideas ?